# How could I use jQuery .closest() to determine nearest image and pass the path to PHP function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pinterest

I am trying to write a Wordpress shortcode that will be smart enough to find the closest image to the shortcodes placement inside the HTML view.

I would like to use jQuery to determine what the nearest image is and then pass it to the function below. I should mention that it is possible for the shortcode to be used multiple times in a post.

I have looked into using `.closest()` to achieve this but I am unsure how to pass this information to my function.

```php
function pinterest_post() {

global $post;
$icon_url = urlencode(site_url().'/wp-content/themes/Kin/images/pinterest.png');
$posturl = urlencode(get_permalink());
$pinurl = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$posturl.'&media='.$icon_url;
$pinurl .= '&description='.urlencode(get_the_title());

return '
    <div class="pinterest_post">
        <a href="'.$pinurl.'"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Kin/images/pinterest.png"/></a>
    </div>';
}

add_shortcode('pin', 'pinterest_post');
```

Any suggestions to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `closest` method only looks at ancestor elements. `img` elements can't have children, so that's definitely not what you're looking for. What do you mean by "closest"?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "nearest image"? Closest only searches self and ancestors.

Comment: To answer James and bhamlin, what I mean by closest is when the user will put the phrase [pin] in their content, it will be next to an image. I hope to detect the nearest img element to [pin].

Comment: When you say "next to an image", do you mean that [pin] is guaranteed to be at the same level of the DOM hierarchy? If so, that simplifies things greatly.

Comment: @Kato yes that is how I intend for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rethinking my approach I found it to be the easiest to allow the user to specify the URL of the image as a parameter of the shortcode. This will ultimately give them greater control over which image is shown and would prevent having to transverse the DOM multiple times for each instance of [pin] in a post.

My modified function and example usage:

```
function pinterest_post($atts = '') {

    global $post;

    $image_fallback = get_bloginfo(template_url).'/images/logo-green-for-website.gif';
    $icon_url = get_bloginfo(template_url).'/images/pinterest.png';

    extract(shortcode_atts(array('path' => $image_fallback,), $atts));
    $image_url = $path;

    $posturl = urlencode(get_permalink());

    $pinurl = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$posturl;
    $pinurl .= '&description='.urlencode(get_the_title());
    $pinurl .= '&media='.$image_url;

    return '
        <div class="pinterest_post">
            <a href="'.$pinurl.'"><img src="'.$icon_url.'"/></a>
        </div>';
}

add_shortcode('pin', 'pinterest_post');
```

Usage inside a Wordpress post:

[pin path="http://www.site.com/image.jpg"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function to determine the offset of an element relative to the document.

Then with a simple mathematical distance formula you can compute the distance between any two elements: `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`

So, to wrap it all up:

1. determine the offset of the *pin* element
2. find all images in the document
3. determine the image with the minimum distance to the pin element based on its offset
4. do whatever you want with it

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/u3zGR/) in action :)

If instead of this *mathematical* definition of closest you want

- the `img` element which is found in the same DOM parent as the `pin`, and at the same level then you should check out the [`$('.pin').siblings('img')`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector
- or if you want at any level you could do something like [`$('.pin').parent().find('img')`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: These are both great suggestions for finding the elements! The only problem with this is the user would need to apply the class to the image when placing it. I was hoping to make it as simple as them entering [pin] in their and it would do the rest.If I need to have them do that I think it would be just as easy to let them paste the url of the image and pass it as shortcode option. +1 for the assist.

Comment: Probably you need some way to locate the short tag in the DOM. WordPress must provide something to do that. At which point, you would replace `.pin` in Dan's example with that element.